# C++ Regarding Copying Array to Vector and calling its variable / functions

Tags: c++

I got a array of this kind

```
VehicleTwoD *vehicletwod[100];
```

Then i create this vector

```
vector<VechicleTwoD*> sortVector;
```

Then i did this

```
//arrayCounter is an integer that record the element count of array vehicletwod
sortVector.assign(vehicletwod, vehicletwod+ arrayCounter);
```

But now i try call a function of vehicletwod by using

```
sortVector->getName();
```

It doesnt work, error message was sortVector does not have such function. how can i retrieve it or its impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sortVector` is of type `vector<VehicleTwoD*>` (I'm assuming that's what you meant), so it doesn't have that method. You probably want to call the method on an element in vector, in which case you can do:

```
sortVector[0]->getName();
```

which would call the method on the vector's first element.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to invoke the function on `sortVector[0]`? (or any other member of the aggregate?)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you just need to say which element of the vector you want to call.

```
sortVector[i]->getName();
```